# Detect squat gesture with algorithmic method

Tags: kinect

Using the kinect toolbox, detecting simple swipe gestures etc using algorithms such as for detecting a swipe to right gesture

```
protected override void LookForGesture()
    {
        // Swipe to right
        if (ScanPositions((p1, p2) => Math.Abs(p2.Y - p1.Y) < SwipeMaximalHeight, // Height
            (p1, p2) => p2.X - p1.X > -0.01f, // Progression to right
            (p1, p2) => Math.Abs(p2.X - p1.X) > SwipeMinimalLength, // Length
            SwipeMininalDuration, SwipeMaximalDuration)) // Duration
        {
            RaiseGestureDetected("SwipeToRight");
            return;
        }
```

or detecting a hand ove head posture:

```
bool CheckHandOverHead(Vector3? headPosition, Vector3? handPosition)
    {
        if (!handPosition.HasValue || !headPosition.HasValue)
            return false;

        if (handPosition.Value.Y < headPosition.Value.Y)
            return false;

        if (Math.Abs(handPosition.Value.X - headPosition.Value.X) > MaxRange)
            return false;

        if (Math.Abs(handPosition.Value.Z - headPosition.Value.Z) > MaxRange)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

How would it be possible to detect a 'Squat' gesture or posture. Im assuming it will be similiar to the examples above, but how would you detect if the hip joint passes below the knee joints to detect a full range squat.

Any ideas on a method or are there libraries available that simulate a squat motion?

Answer (score 0):

I would check with the Y of the joints for the detecting if the hips go beneath the knee, however many people don't do full squats.

One type of comparing gestures that works for me, is to have a collection of points from the frames that holds some example points of the exercise you should be doing. Then you transpose that skeleton onto the user's skeleton, and compare the distance of the joints of the user to the stored position joints.